# Resharper is suddenly showing red for Razor syntax

Tags: c#, razor, resharper

I don't know, all of sudden Razor syntax showing in Red. I suspended and resumed and also closed VS and restarted still the same. Anything else to do?

[image]

Comment: are you missing a namespace?

Comment: I just check I added new css class in _layout.cshtml. Which is not effecting on browsers.

Comment: I had the problem before, try cleaning the solution and building it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the references in the /Web.config and the Views/Web.config. If they are correct, try a clean and rebuild. If that still does not work, you can manually delete the bin folder and VS will recreate it anew.