# ReSharper intermittently showing red errors for valid Razor code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, resharper

When editing a CSHTML page, ReSharper is intermittedly showing some valid Razor syntax in red indicating an error. The syntax is red when I open the file, turns normal when I make an edit, then turns red again after a save:

[image: ReSharper CSHTML error]

Even when red, the code builds successfully and ReSharper even gives correct information about the syntax on hover:

[image]

My environment is:

- ReSharper 10.0.2
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1
- ASP.NET 4.5
- MVC 5

I have tried the solutions offered in other questions (e.g. [ReSharper "can not resolve symbol" even when project builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15713167/resharper-can-not-resolve-symbol-even-when-project-builds), [Resharper is suddenly showing red for Razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898607/resharper-is-suddenly-showing-red-for-razor-syntax)) like Suspending/Resuming ReSharper, clearing caches, etc. I even tried reinstalling ReSharper entirely but none of that helped.

Potentially relevant (?) is that I recently installed MVC 3 and MVC 4 for other projects, but I have since uninstalled them again.

Any suggestions for what might be causing this? Could it be a ReSharper bug somehow?

**UPDATE:**

This actually only happends when a ReSharper code cleanup is run and then a save is made. I had an extension which did this automatically on every save, but having disabled that the actual flow is:

- Make edits - ***OK***
- Save - ***OK***
- Clean up - ***OK***
- Save - ***RED***

I am using the *Default: Full Cleanup* profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a symptom of a known ReSharper bug, due to be fixed in version 10.1

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-455788